# Combine pattern with maxlength of input field

Tags: javascript, html, regex, jquery-mobile

Is it possible to combine a pattern attribute with a maxlength attribute on an input field in jquerymobile?

```
<input name="aNumber" type="number" pattern="[0-9]{6}" maxlength="6" placeholder="dddddd" value="">
<input name="anotherNumber" type="number" pattern="[0-9]{3,4}" maxlength="4" placeholder="ddd(d)" value="">
```

I want the big numberpad to appear but that only works using `pattern="[0-9]*"`. Unfortunately the maxlength attribute is not respected in any case.

What I want is a numeric keypad to appear (the big one/dial; the iPhone apparently has two: only numbers/dial and numbers with special chars) letting the user input up to 6 or 3 to 4 numeric chars.

---

Edit: Applied @raina77ow 's suggestion and that works for the moment, but still it feels not right so I'm open to advice!

```
<input name="aNumber" type="tel" pattern="[0-9]*" maxlength="6" placeholder="dddddd" value="">
```

Comment: What about type="tel" maxlength="6" combination, won't it help?

Comment: @raina77ow That helped indeed! Feels dirty though...

Comment: Why isn't `maxlength` respected?

Answer (score 3):

{6} means exactly 6 Digits
{0,6} means minimum 0 digits and maximum 6 digits

Answer (score 1):

type="tel" pattern="{X,6}" maxlength="6"

if you wanna limit input to strictly numbers (as in math numbers not telephone numbers) go with:

pattern="[0-9]{X,6}"

Where x is an integer number between 0 and 6 will get you the minimum of X and maximum of 6 digits for input.

If you type pattern this way, you need maxlength only for browsers that don't support pattern attribute, I would keep it.